# Is it possible to make inset not behave as edge support for subdivision surface modifier?

Tags: subdivision-surface, extrude, bevel

I would like to use inset, bevel or extrude tool with subdivision modifier, but when I make more loops they bring out cube attributes- as edge support, I would like that they follow curvature. Is that possible? I would like to use inset to ad  new topology on my creature, when I add 2 or three loops they flat everything.
[this is mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MeDx.jpg)

[this is from book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sK5gs.png)

Comment: You can use edge tools for example edge crease. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html#edge-crease

Comment: Hello. You cannot prevent subsurf modifier from using existing loops. There are ways around it however. Attach a preview of your mesh, then it'll be easier to reccomend something specific.

Comment: I edit question because I don't know how to add image here in comment.

Comment: Images should always go on the posts, not the comments see [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: I am still searching way to do this better. I now model with cage on, and after I inset move edge loop, use smooth, but it changes a lot mine meshes with shrink - than I use resize, to reshape. I would like that it would be possible to ad that loop and keep  more roundness.